# Python check variable, element for part of a string

Tags: python

Im new to Python and am having issues with lists, elements,etc. I have this code:

```
order_payment = Api.which_api('order_payments', 'None', '26', 'None')

# now that we have info from order_payment, obtain the rest of the vars we need
order_id      = order_payment['order_id']

order_payment = Api.which_api('order_payments', 'None', '26', 'None')
orders        = Api.which_api('orders', 'None', order_id, 'items')

# your loop
for orders in orders['items']:
    oid  = orders['order_id']
    item = orders['item_name']
    print(item)

    sub = 'Download'
    print (s for s in item if sub in s)
```

When I do print(item) I get this returned:
Norton Antivirus 2014 - Download - 1 User / 1 PC - 1 Year Subscription

I want to check this variable to see if it has Download in it(like this one does) I looked on here and found the code Im trying(sub = 'Download') but that is not working. Basically Im trying to set up a if condition. If this element 'item_name' has 'Download' in it do this. How do i check the vairable for this

Answer (score 1):

Use the in operator

`if "Download" in item:
     print`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you would be to use `try` and `except` in your python code for better results.

```
try :
   item = orders['item_name']
   print(item)

   sub = 'Download'
   print (s for s in item if sub in s)
except:
   pass
```